# apiaxle not working as expected

Tags: curl, apiaxle

I was just checking out  [apiaxle](http://www.apiaxle.com). I was able to install it properly follwoing the documentation at [Documentation](http://apiaxle.com/docs/try-it-now/). However, it seems there is a problem now. After installing i ran `$ apiaxle-proxy -f 1 -p 3000 -q` As stated in the doc, i got the error as This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<error>
<type>ApiUnknown</type>
<message>No api specified (via subdomain)</message>
</error>
```

Now i have an application running at localhost:9000. I want apiaxle to sit on top of it and any other links such as localhost:9000/test and localhost:9000/test/param. To begin doing this i added the below highlighted code in my `/etc/hosts` file as suggested by the docs. The file now looks like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       GBH-201505-0052
#apiaxle This line and below added by me
127.0.0.1       myapp.api.localhost
```

After this, when i run `$ apiaxle-proxy -f 1 -p 3000 -q` and hit http://myapp.api.localhost:3000/ i see the same error as above.No change at all. The doc says that the error would be same but with a different message. Anyways, i now proceed to create and add the api by the commands:

```
$ apiaxle
axle> api "myapp" create endPoint="localhost:9000"
axle> key "1234" create
axle> api myapp linkkey "1234"
```

Now if i do a `$ curl 'http://myapp.api.localhost:3000/?api_key=1234'` or `curl 'http://myapp.api.localhost:3000/test/param?api_key=1234'` i get the perfect response as expected. However when i copy paste the same url in a browser i get a "Web page not available error". Also if i try to get the stats or even view the apis i get **ApiUnKnown** error. For example i tried the below 3 commands and at both i got **ApiUnKnown** error. The commands were:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000/v1/api'
curl 'http://localhost:3000/v1/api'
curl 'http://localhost:3000/v1/api/myapp/stats?granularity=hour&format_timstamp=ISO'
```

The detailed error for all the above:`{"meta":{"version":1,"status_code":404},"results":{"error":{"type":"ApiUnknown","message":"No api specified (via subdomain)"}}}`

If that was not strange, here is one more interesting thing. If i go to the apiaxle console and see the apis and keys then myapp is there and is being listed.

```
$apiaxle
axle> apis
[ 'myapp']
axle> keys
[ '1234']
```

What is happening? Can someone help me understand how to do this? The documentation is quite scarce in this respect.

Comment: Any comments please? Would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your nginx.conf to accept requests and proxy back to apiaxle. [apiaxle docs](http://apiaxle.com/docs/try-it-now/) start to talk about this at the bottom.

The flow is essentially having nginx to take your request (say `/nice_uri/123` and send the information back to apiaxle, who then sends the request to your `endPoint` `/test` on the app server and gets the response. From what i can tell you are just going to the `endPoint` right off the bat. You want the endPoint to be hidden, basically.

good luck , as you will need it to grok it all. ymmv of course, but it works if you can get over the lack of support.

Comment: hi...thanks for the reply but i am completely new to nginx...can you help some more... Also why do i need to do this even for localhost...i am getting {"error":{"type":"ApiUnknown","message":"No api specified (via subdomain)"}}} when i try any  of the url 'http://localhost:3000/v1/api'
curl 'http://localhost:3000/v1/api' (also apis)
curl 'http://localhost:3000/v1/api/myapp/stats?granularity=hour&format_timstamp=ISO'... Shouldn't it return atleast the list of apis... if i type apis in the console after doing apiaxle i get the list